# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" when trying to use content of Rails array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In Rails 5 I want to use the content of a Rails array inside Javascript:

in my harddisk_controller.rb:

```
@locations = Harddisk.select(:location).distinct # grab a collection of distinct harddisk locations objects
@harddisk_locations = []
@locations.each do |location|
  @harddisk_locations << location.location # put only the location names into an array
end
```

I'm trying to achieve to load the content of Rails' @harddisk_locations into Javascript's harddisk_locations:

in application.js:

```
var harddisk_locations = [<%= raw @harddisk_locations.to_json %>];
```

But I'm getting the error message with highlight on [<%= raw @harddisk_locations.to_json %>] in my browser console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

I assume Javascript is complaining about the

> <

right after

> [

character. How to fix this?

Comment: View source and see what `var harddisk_locations = [<%= raw @harddisk_locations.to_json %>];` renders as

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're using invalid syntax for `js`. That's why you need to rename `application.js` to `application.js.erb`.

Be aware, if you want to inject a string into erb you need to use quotes:

```
var harddisk_locations = ["<%= somestring %>"];
```

In you case, I guess, `raw @harddisk_locations.to_json` is a valid json, so the quotes are not needed.

Comment: If `raw
@harddisk_locations.to_json` contains a valid json formatted string then the statement is not invalid

Comment: Just curious to know that defining `harddisk_locations` as array is necessary? I mean `@harddisk_locations` is already an array.

Comment: strictly speaking @harddisk_locations is a Hash with besides the location a lot of other attributes.

Answer (score 2):

You are using an ERB syntax inside a .js file. A better solution would be to create a new .js.erb file and add your required code in that file.

A suggestion regarding your code, you can replace existing code with `@harddisk_locations = Harddisk.select(:location).distinct.map(&:location)`

Comment: Even easier: `@harddisk_locations = Harddisk.pluck(:location).uniq`